# How do I get the (X1) (Y1) (Z1) (X2) (Y2) (Z2) in Minecraft bedrock edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to use the `/fill command`, but I'm not sure what these parameters mean. Can someone explain what the X,Y, and Z parameters mean?

```
/fill [X1] [Y1] [Z1] [X2] [Y2] [Z2]
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? It's a little vague right now.  Are you asking how to find specific coordinates within your world to put in the command, or what `[X1]` etc. actually means?

Comment: How to get the numbers

Comment: That... doesn't answer my question, it's still vague.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about the `/fill` command [here](https://www.dummies.com/programming/programming-games/minecraft/how-to-fill-areas-in-minecraft-with-the-fill-command/) but the short version is these are the coordinates of the space you want to fill. If you press the`F3` button on your keyboard you will bring up a menu with your Minecraft coordinates.

The last part of the command (not depicted in the image) is the item to fill the area with.

The article linked uses an example of

```
/fill 1123 20 16 1122 30 -16 minecraft:wool 1 replace
```

This will `replace` all the blocks between the coordinates `1123, 20, 16` and `1122, 30, -16` with white (datatype `1`)  `wool`

Answer (score 0):

Those numbers, simply put, are two coordinates.

X1, Y1, and Z1 are the XYZ coordinates of 1 corner of the area you want to fill.

X2, Y2, and Z2 are the XYZ coordinates of the exact opposite corner of the area you want to fill.

To get these numbers:

1. Press <kbd>F3</kbd> so you can see your current coordinates.
2. Fly to the upper left corner of the area you'd like to fill. Write down your XYZ coordinates.
3. Fly to the lower right corner of the area you'd like to fill. Write down your XYZ coordinates.
4. Use those two sets of XYZ coordinates to use the `/fill` command.

Once you've used it a few times, it becomes a lot easier to understand.